# Is pandas groupby() function always produce a DataFrame with the same order respect to the column we group by?

Tags: python, pandas

Given `pd.DataFrame` `X` with column `id`, is the call to `groupby()` always return a DataFrame with the same order with respect to the column `id`?

`X.groupby('id')[col_name].first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by default, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) sorts the rows on the grouping key(s).

You can disable this behavior by passing `sort=False`:

```
X.groupby('id', sort=False)[col_name].first()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [3, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'col_name': list('abcde')})

   id col_name
0   3        a
1   1        b
2   2        c
3   1        d
4   2        e

df.groupby('id')['col_name'].first()

id
1    b
2    c
3    a
Name: col_name, dtype: object

df.groupby('id', sort=False)['col_name'].first()

id
3    a
1    b
2    c
Name: col_name, dtype: object
```